# Embedding our document viewer in Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, snap.svg

In my website there is a non-video viewer/player (http://www.becomics.com/b/57db0b148f0ac8c86f921bfc). We made it for reading webcomics. It uses Snap.svg and HTML5 technologies.

I was wondering if there is a way to have our viewer embedded on Facebook whenever it is shared (similarly to having a video player embedded in the Facebook feed whenever someone shares a YouTube video).

Is this something that can be done? How?

Comment: No you have to use Flash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+html5+timeline